# Run test are not running as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest, should.js

I run the following test and its not stopping in the actions of the express router
The URL is exactly the url which I put in postman and works ,any idea?

describe('test', function () {

```
it('Should Run///',
    function (done) {

        supertest(app)
            .post('http://localhost:3002//save/test1/test2/test3')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.status.should.equal(200);
                done();
            });

    });

    in the following code its not stopping in the post  (console.log...)what am I missing here?

    module.exports = function (app, express) {

var appRouter = express.Router();
app.use(appRouter);
//Route Application Requests
appRouter.route('*')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log("test");
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending a response in your route handler:

```
appRouter.route('*')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log("test");
        return res.sendStatus(200); // <-- actually send back a response!
    });
```

Also, it seems from your code that you are passing an Express app and not a server to Supertest, in which case you probably need to use this:

```
.post('/save/test1/test2/test3')
```

(instead of a full url)

Comment: Thanks I try it and still its not working, I use webstorm 10 and I able to debug mocha ,currenlty the BP stops in the appRouter.route('*') but the problem is that it not stops in console.log or if I add the return nothing happen....

Comment: Hi , any idea how to proceed?

Comment: I assume that when you send a regular `POST` request to your server the `console.log()` shows up?

Comment: yes sure the request is routed to some logic in post and its working great!

Comment: And `app` in your test is an Express instance, too?